"System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop applications" error when dynamically loading a DLL in .NET 6
I'm using the "Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" package to get the baseboard serial number in a .NET 6 application. My code looks like this:
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
var mobos = searcher.Get();

foreach (var m in mobos)
{
    return m["SerialNumber"].ToString() ?? "";
}

When I run this code in a console application, it works correctly. However, when I create a DLL that executes this code and load that DLL dynamically with LoadContext, I get the following error:
System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop applications.

How can I fix this problem?
Verified Package Installation: Ensured that the "Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" package is installed and referenced in both the console application and the DLL project.
Target Framework: Confirmed that both the console application and the DLL project are targeting .NET
This is the DLL loader:
string dll_Path = Path.GetFullPath(dll_name);
var loadContext = new LoadContext(dll_Path);
var assembly = loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dll_Path);
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyClass");
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("MyMethod");
T function = (T)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), method);
function.DynamicInvoke(inputs);


While debugging you might want to check from where the System.Management assembly was loaded. The nuget package will contain multiple assemblies for different targets. If because of reasons it chooses the wrong one for example the one only  provided to be used by Visual Studio to discover the surface of classes but hasn't implementation you will get errors like that.

You say "dynamically loaded" about what assembly you are talking and from where do you actually load it?

.NET 6 is .NET Core 6. Unless you specify that the project targets Windows, the generated application is cross-platform and can't use Windows APIs. Try changing  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> to <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework> in .csproj

The assembly I'm talking about is a DLL I created that contains the code to retrieve the baseboard serial number.

The DLL loader part added to the question.

Apparently this is due to using .Net Core...
I found this: How to use it
This is what worked:
in the csproj file. Add the following usually at the beginning:

<PropertyGroup> 
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>

Reload project  


this method not worked.

This worked on my development machine only for the problem to pop up again when deploying to a new machine.
